# relation between representations of homology class

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Let X be a topological space, for its homology class [f], we can alway construct a simplicial complex K_f by gluing "cancelling boundary pairs" of f and an induced continuous map f' from K_f to X. However such construction is in general not unique(the glue method is not canonical), can we construct cobordisms (in some sense) among these glued complexes(It might be true when X is a compact smooth manifold, how about in general case)?

Comment: It sounds like you reinvented simplicial cohomology... In short the answer is yes: two simplicial cycles are 'cobordant' if they

Comment: bound a cycle of one higher dimension... In other words if they're boundaries in the usual sense of simplicial homology!

Comment: When I was in college my professor gave a couple of lectures about recovering singular homology by taking cobordism classes of PL-manifold with singularities in codimension 2. Unfortunately I have no reference for that

Comment: A quick way to see that that bordism thy recovers the usual one is to note that it's a homology theory and when evaluated on a point you get Z or Z/2 (oriented or not) in degree 0 and nothing elsewhere: the cone on any pseudomanifold of dimension bigger than 0 is a pseudomanifold with boundary the one you started with.

Comment: In my knowledge simplicial homology only defined over \Delta-complexes, for general topological space the cobordism classes of this kind of chains form "circuit groups", which coincide with simplicial homology groups when  X is good enough. So far I did not find reference showing that such groups are isomorphic to singular homology groups.

Comment: @DenisNardin This sounds like Kreck's stratifolds. I don't have access to mathscinet right now, so I cannot give you a more precise reference.

Comment: Many thanks for Prof. Peter J. Kahn's reply. This is true for general topological spaces and is called Rourke-Sanderson Theorem.